# Is it necessary to use XMPPRosterCoreDataStorage in Chat app?

Tags: ios, agsxmpp

I am creating an i OS app chat application. I have integrated XMPPFramework in my app.
Can i create my own core data model and store all roster info in that model instead of XMPPRosterCoreDataStorage ?

Please suggest me..

Comment: i think you should read this https://github.com/robbiehanson/XMPPFramework/wiki/XMPP_CoreData

Comment: Thank you so much Dipak, i am referring the same link.

Comment: and this will be great help. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/xmppframework

Comment: Great forum Dipak. thanks again